# Kubernetes Node healthcheck

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I am trying to understand the Node-Controller in Kubernetes. Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#heartbeats) mentions that node heartbeats are done using NodeStatus and LeaseObject updates. Someone, please explain why both mechanisms are needed for monitoring node health.
Does Kubernetes master internally use a job/cronjob for a node health check processing?

Answer (score 1):

[Lease](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#lease-v1-coordination-k8s-io) is a lightweight resource, which improves the performance of the node heartbeats as the cluster scales.

The Lease objects are tracked as a way of helping the heartbeats to continue functioning efficiently as a cluster scales up. According to the docs, this would be their primary function relating to heartbeats.

Whereas the `NodeStatus` is used for Heartbeats by the kubelet, `NodeStatus` is also an important signal for other controllers in k8s.

For example: the k8s scheduler is responsible for scheduling pods on nodes. It tries to find the best fit for a node to optimize memory, cpu, and other usage on the node. It wouldn't however want to schedule a pod on a node with [node status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#node-status) condition set to `NetworkUnavailable: true` or some other condition which would make the pod unsuitable to run on that node.

If there is a signal or signals that you don't know or understand, there is a good chance there is a controller that uses that field or signal to accomplish its logic.

**EDIT:**

The node-controller is a part of the [kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/):

> The Kubernetes controller manager is a daemon that embeds the core
> control loops shipped with Kubernetes. In applications of robotics and
> automation, a control loop is a non-terminating loop that regulates
> the state of the system. In Kubernetes, a controller is a control loop
> that watches the shared state of the cluster through the apiserver and
> makes changes attempting to move the current state towards the desired
> state. Examples of controllers that ship with Kubernetes today are the
> replication controller, endpoints controller, namespace controller,
> and serviceaccounts controller.

Logically, each controller is a separate process, but to reduce complexity, they are all compiled into a single binary and run in a single process.

**EDIT_2**:

Based on your latest comments, we have 2 additional points to address:

> 1. "how the node-controller processes the node health check"

While implementing k8s, you probably don't need to know this level of detail. All the details which should be useful for you are already in the [linked public docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-controller-manager). There is no need to worry about that but I understand that it brought the more practical question:

> 2. I am not sure how much load a big cluster can generate.

This is where the [Considerations for large clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/) comes to help. It will show you how to handle big clusters and which tools are there at your disposal when it comes to managing them.

Comment: *@Wiktor Thanks* for the answer. Yes, it answered my question partially. Indeed NodeStatus is used by kubelet to notify not just node heartbeats. And regarding Leases, I found a link that helped in understanding Leases more.
https://github.com/hongchaodeng/community/blob/c0195f0382cee987cf9be0a411da553c5c261b0d/keps/0008-node-heartbeat.md

I still need to understand how the node-controller processes the node health check, say in case of a missed health check.

Comment: Hi @Kiran. Glad it's more clear for you now. In case of a missed heartbeat the Node Controller updates the `NodeReady` [Condition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#condition) to `ConditionUnknown` indicating that the Node might be down for any reason.

Comment: *@Wiktor* Yes. Node-controller has to periodically check the heartbeat to know whether node is alive or not. I guess that will be done by some kind of job/cronjob at node-controller. I am looking for some references for the same..

Comment: Actually, the node-controller is a deamon that embeds the core control loops shipped with Kubernetes. I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: *@Wiktor* Thanks for the info. I am aware of the kube-controller daemon. As you rightly pointed out, I want to know how the control loop processing is done. Because the Kube-controller runs in active-passive mode, all the monitoring is done by a single Kube-controller node. I am not sure how much load a big cluster can generate. I assume actual processing of checking the health of nodes or making sure the required number of pods are running is offloaded to some kind of worker Jobs.